# How to get $route.matched property in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm sure I must be doing something wrong because I haven't seen other bug reports with this behavior, but I can't seem to get `$route` to contain the `matched` property. It does contain all the other documented properties.

I first noticed this in a larger Vue SPA, but can replicate in a smaller reproduction. Here's a CodePen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/daveaglick/pen/KZgror

If you switch the CodePen to debug view and open Vue devtools, you'll notice there's no `matched` property:

[image]

So the question is: given the code in the pen what am I doing wrong? Do I need to "turn on" reporting of the path matches?

(For reference, the `$route.matched` property is documented near the bottom here: https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html)

Comment: No repro for me, I can see the `$0.__vue__.$route.matched` property when having the root component selected in the elements panel

Comment: @Ferrybig I'm not sure what you mean... If you open the Vue devtools and select the `<Root>` component you see `$route.matched` differently than my screenshot? If some other way, what steps are you taking?

Comment: Vue devtools don't seem to work for me, but if I type `document.getElementById('app').__vue__.$route` in the console, I see the matched part on the route object itself.

Comment: @Ferrybig That's really strange - I wonder why it doesn't show up in devtools. I can confirm it's actually there though. If you write this up as an answer I'd be happy to accept.